# Simulator and iPhone make different web requests with the same code

Tags: iphone, swift, ios-simulator, alamofire

Woah, this is weird. I've looked at my web server logs and, when running my code on the simulator, it makes the following request...

> 2016-07-08 13:00:10 172.31.52.24 GET /admin/api/cities/Lond

But when I publish to my device, it does this...

> 2016-07-08 13:04:03 172.31.52.24 GET /admin/api/cities pageindex=1&term=Londo

How is this possible?

This is the web request code...

```
public func DoWebRequest(url: String, parameters: [String: AnyObject]? = nil) -> Promise<AnyObject> {

        return Promise { fulfill, reject in

            let request = Alamofire.request(.GET, webServiceUrl + url)

            request.responseString { response in

                guard response.result.error == nil else {

                    reject(response.result.error!)

                    return
                }

                fulfill(response.result.value!)
            }
        }
    }
```

Repository...

```
public func fetchCities(term: String) -> Promise<[City]> {

    return DoWebRequest("cities/\(term)") { self.BindCity($0) }
}
```

Service...

```
public func getCities(term: String) -> Promise<[City]> {

    return tourRepository.fetchCities(term)
}
```

Client...

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

        if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text?.characters.count >= 4 {

            tourService.getCities(searchController.searchBar.text!)

                .then { result -> Void in

                    self.cities = result

                }

        } else {

            self.cities = []
        }
    }
```

Comment: you probably miss typing London

Comment: Why would that result in a different URL?

Comment: can you share the code?

Comment: @IshmeetSingh Updated.

Comment: probably this has to do something with the server. server might also be paginating result. try printing your url on console before sending the request.

Comment: Break points and NSLog don't work on the device.

Comment: I think this is because old code is being copied to the device. I deleted all the files and now it won't compile because the linked projects can't be found - hence my theory that it hasn't been updating the code in the linked projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App's embedded frameworks were out of date when running on the device.